# Automatic database indexing

Tags: database, oracle, indexing, azure-sql-database, database-indexes

I have a database which is used by a multi-tenant application. In this database workloads are dynamic and change continuously. Therefore I have to allocate a DA to continuously manage the database. But I thought to use an automated service for this task such as Azure SQL Database Advisor - Automatic index management (platform is not important - I am OK with using MS sql server or oracle or other RDBMS).

I want to know how these automated indexes are actually working.Can I replace database administrator with these automatic indexers. I read that whenever a query execution plan is generated it will find out all the useful indexes to execute that query. Then it uses the indexes which really exist and cache some data about indexes which don't exist. If an index data is cached again and again the sql adviser will show that as a recommended index. But I want to know can we relay on this, what about update and insert queries? If I have a table where records are frequently updated, these automated indexing systems will consider that?

Comment: In general a dba does a whole lot more than determine indexes. You can't seriously be thinking this can replace one.

Comment: @HLGEM - I am aware that DAs so more than indexing. But I am just wondering whether I can release a DA from indexing tasks

Answer (score 4):

Note that Index Advisor is only available in SQL Database (Azure).

In the background Index Advisor is a machine learning algorithm, a relatively simple and quite effective one. It will analyze your workload, see if you would benefit from indexes. If he thinks you would it will show you as a recommendation - if you turn automatic index creation/dropping on it will actually create the index. To understand better how it works take a look at [Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Data-Exposed/Azure-SQL-DB-Index-Advisor). Note that before you apply a recommendation you can have an estimated impact.

Now the algorithm can make mistakes, right? So once the recommendation is applied it can automatically be reverted [based on its performance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-advisor-portal/#enable-automatic-index-management).

Also note that next to Index Advisor you can check the [Query Performance Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-query-performance/) that will show the performance of you queries. So this can help your DBA diagnose other, non-index related problems.

But note that Index Advisor will not drop and create for you new indexes every hour, it takes for him a day or two. So if your database's workload is changing very fast then I am not sure any automatic management tool or DBA will react quickly enough for your workload.